# PayPal IPN not returning custom variables on mobile devices

Tags: php, android, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am using PayPal on my website, but I am unable to retrieve the information I need when the form is submitted from an Android or iOS device. These values are stored in fields with names such as on0 or os1 and when the form is submitted from a desktop I can find them in the option_name[x] selection_name[x] variables. These last variables are not defined when I submit the form from a mobile device. I ran tests to make sure that the values submitted by the form on all platforms are the same. The problem comes from the values returned by PayPal.
Any idea what is causing that? How does PayPal generate these variables?
Thanks

Comment: you should not rely on paypal to return anything but the status of the payment, all other data should be handled internally.

Comment: Some things should be done only after PayPal confirms the payment for security reasons, and the only alternative I see is using session variables which are less secure.